# Proxy problems in Google API

Tags: node.js, proxy, google-api, google-calendar-api

Now I'm developing a Google Calendar application with node.js programs. And now I'm facing proxy troubles.

Firstly I've tried google's test sample and it worked if my node.js program accesses Internet directly (I mean without proxy). But when I tried to run same program in proxy environment, it failed. I use same code below link except for proxy settings.

[quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs)

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var readline = require('readline');
 var google = require('googleapis');
 var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

 google.options.proxy = 'https://xxx:12345'; // I added
 process.env.HTTP_PROXY = 'http://xxx:12345'; // I added
 process.env.HTTPS_PROXY = 'https://xxx:12345'; // I added
 ///
```

It failed when trying to get a token. Actually this proxy is valid because I use same proxy setting on the same pc.

```
Error while trying to retrieve access token { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=139916950681408:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:787:
] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

For debugging, I added code to printing options at TunnelingAgent():google-auth-library/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js. And I confirmed 
proxy settings are printed like below.

```
options: { proxy:
   { host: 'xxx',
     port: 12345,
     proxyAuth: null,
     headers:
      { 'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.9.7',
        host: 'accounts.google.com:443' } },
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.9.7' },
  ca: undefined,
  cert: undefined,
  key: undefined,
  passphrase: undefined,
  pfx: undefined,
  ciphers: undefined,
  rejectUnauthorized: undefined,
  secureOptions: undefined,
  secureProtocol: undefined }
```

What happens?

My refs:

- [specifying a default proxy and auth to be used for each request](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#example-specifying-a-default-proxy-and-auth-to-be-used-for-each-request)
- [issue with Sent requests via HTTP proxy](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/64)

Comment: I found a proxy setting does not affect to getToken. I reported this problem as a [issue](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/65). My temporary solution is add a proxy property into request options directly. I doubt google.options.proxy doesn't work in getting token. After getting token, google.options.proxy looks working correctly.